# How do I change the order of Styles options being displayed in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I've customized the Styles in Word and have used this Template for years. On 12/12/22, the order of the Styles has completely changed so that the Styles I use most frequently (Title, Heading 1, Heading 2) are now on the 2nd row and instead of being able to quickly use these, I have to hit the dropdown every time.

Why this suddenly happened is something I'd like to understand to prevent it from happening again...**BUT**...the only thing I really care about now is how I can move the 3-5 styles I frequently use to the top row. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Set a different priority using Manage Styles and options. See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

I came across this question and answer when trying to reorder my Styles, but didn't find it completely functional. The most important step I needed was to *reorder* my Styles in a highly specific way.

If you want to *fully* customize the "Recommended" options, as described by John, there are ***TWO*** steps you should follow.

There are two steps:
The first is selecting the Styles to be showed, which John showed and I'll repeat here.
The second is where you *actually* get to control the order of the Styles as they appear.

#### First step *(thank you John)* - enable "Recommended" options for Styles

1. On the "Home" tab ribbon, click the "Styles" button to show more Styles
2. In the dropdown that appears, click "Options..." which should open a new window
3. In the "Style Pane Options" make sure you have the Recommended options selected.
4. **Make sure to click OK when you're finished!**

[image: First section - enabling recommendations]

#### Second step - change the priorities of your Styles

1. On the "Home" tab ribbon, click the "Styles" button to show more Styles
2. In the dropdown that appears, click "Manage Styles" which is represented by an 'A' with a checkmark on it
3. This shows a new window where you can move around the different priorities of your Style
4. **Make sure to click OK when you're finished!**

Because we've already selected "Recommended", the priority of each picked Style will automatically be picked up. The lower the number, the higher the priority. It's generally considered not great practice to have two items with the same priority unless you don't care about where they end up. You can assign values to specific Styles, move them up/down, etc which is all highly useful.

[image: Second section - picking Style priorities]

Answer (score 2):

Open Word, See the Style Icon in the main ribbon.

Use the Pull Down (bottom right of the Styles icon) and then at the bottom, see options.

Inside Options, there is a (fairly simple) set of reordering options.

These should help you.

.

[image: Word Styles - Sort]